# Google script - parse json response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jsonparser

This is the json **response** (from my multiple choice field [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sofoklis_stouraitis/zLzfpb1u/8/)) that i'm trying to parse:

> {"selected":true,"disabled":false,"text":"Ctr","id":"Ctr","title":"","_resultId":"select2-selectcountry-result-je97-Ctr","element":{}},
>
> {"selected":true,"disabled":false,"text":"Title
>    Part1","id":"TitlePart1","title":"","_resultId":"select2-selectcountry-result-uv7s-TitlePart1","element":{}},
>
> {"selected":false,"disabled":false,"text":"Milan","id":"Milan","_resultId":"select2-selectcountry-result-bmba-Milan","element":{}}]

I need to get: {"*id*":value},{"*id*":value},{"*id*":value} ...

```
{id:Ctr},{"id":"TitlePart1"},{"id":"Milan} ...
```

To achieve this result, I'm using this code:

```
var response = (JSON.stringify($('#selectcountry').select2('data')) );        
var json = JSON.parse(response);
        var dataSet = json;
        var row = [],
        data;
       for(var i in json){
       data = dataSet[i];
       row.push({'id': json[i].id})
       }

   sheet.getRange(6,1).setValue(row);
```

But in this way I get only the first id:value:

```
{id:Ctr}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Use setValues instead

Comment: @TheMaster I tryed .setValues(row); and didn't get any result, while with .setValues([row]); I get only the first value selected.

Comment: You seem to be missing the opening square bracked. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s='[{"selected":true,"disabled":false,"text":"Ctr","id":"Ctr","title":"","_resultId":"select2-selectcountry-result-je97-Ctr","element":{}},{"selected":true,"disabled":false,"text":"Title Part1","id":"TitlePart1","title":"","_resultId":"select2-selectcountry-result-uv7s-TitlePart1","element":{}},{"selected":false,"disabled":false,"text":"Milan","id":"Milan","_resultId":"select2-selectcountry-result-bmba-Milan","element":{}}]';

function findId() {
  var d=JSON.parse(s);
  var ids=[];
  d.forEach(function(o){
    ids.push(o.id);
  });
  Logger.log(ids);
  //Add this
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,3).setValues([ids]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Cooper. Using your code, the log show me the 3 ids "[Ctr, TitlePart1, Milan]" but when I set the value in the sheet using the formula "sheet.getRange(6,1).setValue(ids);" I got only the first value "Ctr".

Comment: This is not meant to be a custom cell formula?  I doubt that cell formulas even have access to JSON.parse() and you can't change surround cells with a cell formula.  You need to read the restrictions for cell formulas in the documenation.

Comment: No. Sorry for my english. Using "sheet.getRange(6,1).setValue(ids);" below the logger. when I run the script on the sheet appear only the value "Ctr" even if in the log there are "[Ctr, TitlePart1, Milan]".

Comment: First of all ids is an array not a single value.  Secondly, you can't really use setValues because ids is not a 2d array but you could post it as a row with `setValues([ids])`